# How do I know if I can accept or reject the hypothesis?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, cramers-v

I have to test a hypothesis that religion is connected to conservatism. I have recoded my variables and I have done a cross-tab and cramer's v test. I am not sure what these values tell me about my hypothesis. Does anyone possibly know if I can accept or reject my hypothesis through these tests?[image]

Comment: Welcome to this site! If this is homework, please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its wiki.

Comment: Either the chi-squared test or its Yates-corrected version is a valid way to test the null hypothesis $H_0$ that your Religion and Vote categories are independent. [The 'expected counts' in the computation of the chi-squared statistic are based on H0.] The very small P-values indicate the $H_0$ is rejected at the 5% level of significance (or any reasonable smaller level down to $\approx 0).$ Such large values of the test statistic are very unlikely to occur if $H_0$ were true. // For cell counts as large as yours the Yates correction is not necessary. // In Answ. format I verify the P-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chi-squared test in R:

```
MAT = rbind(c(1097,2209), c(344,1340))
MAT
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1097 2209
[2,]  344 1340
chisq.test(MAT, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 88.37, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

If $H_0$ is true then the chi-squared statistic (`X-squared` in the output) has very nearly the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=1)$ and
hence expected value $1.$ The probability that the statistic exceeds 89.331 can be computed in R as follows $(0$ to eight or more places):

```
1 - pchisq(88.37, 1)
[1] 0
```

If the statistic exceeds $3.841$ or $6.635,$ then $H_0$ is rejected at the 5% or 1% level, respectively.

```
qchisq(c(.95,.99), 1)
[1] 3.841459 6.634897
```

Another test for such a $2\times 2$ table is Fisher's Exact
Test. It is based on a hypergeometric distribution. (Wikipedia has an extensive discussion). This test is often used when
counts in the table are too small for the chi-squared test
to give reliable P-values.  In R:

```
fisher.test(MAT)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  MAT
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
  true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.680566 2.229396
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.934191
```